# Why is there run time overhead on the first time a method is called in Java?

Tags: java, performance, program-entry-point, execution-time

I was measuring execution time of my code and found some weird behavior when making the first call to a method (from the main method). Here is my code, please have a look at this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int iNum = input.nextInt();
        long lStartTime = System.nanoTime();

        // ***********(First call in main) Calling isPrime *************

        lStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        printResult(isPrime(iNum));
        System.out.println("Time Consumed in first call-: " 
                + (System.nanoTime() - lStartTime));

        // ***********(Second call in main) Calling isPrime *************
        lStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        printResult(isPrime(iNum));
        System.out.println("Time Consumed in second call-: "
                + (System.nanoTime() - lStartTime));
    }
}

private static boolean isPrime(int iNum) {
    boolean bResult = true;

    if (iNum <= 1 || iNum != 2 && iNum % 2 == 0) {
        bResult = false;
    } else {
        double iSqrt = Math.sqrt((double) iNum);
        for (int i = 3; i < iSqrt; i += 2) {
            if (iNum % i == 0) {
                bResult = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return bResult;
}

private static void printResult(boolean bResult) {
    if (bResult)
        System.out.println("\nIt's prime number.");
    else
        System.out.println("\nIt's not prime number.");
}
```

#### Input

```
5
```

#### Output

```
It's prime number.
Time Consumed in first call-: 484073

It's prime number.
Time Consumed in second call-: 40710
```

#### Description

I have depicted only one test case of input and output above. But, there is always a difference in execution time between the first method invocation and the second one.

I have also tried more than two methods calls in the similar way and found that there is not such a huge difference between the other calls except one. I'm getting right execution time around **40710ns** (this execution time could be different on your system) for the rest of calls except first method call which is **484073ns**. Easily I can see that there is time overhead of **484073 - 40710 = 443363ns** (approx) in first method call, but why is it happening? What is the root cause?

Comment: The first invocation generally requires compilation of the bytecode (a one time cost). After that, active JIT makes subsequent calls faster (over time).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Is this compilation of byte code(a one time cost)  only for first   invocation of any method(out of multiple different method)? let us say there are two methods `isPrime` and `isPrime2` and invocation sequence of these two methods in `main` is `isPrime` , `isPrime2` , `isPrime` , `isPrime2`. So whether the compilation of byte code(a one time cost)  would happen for the first invocation of `isPrime2`?

Comment: From the Wikipedia entry on [Just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), *JIT causes a slight delay to a noticeable delay in initial execution of an application, due to the time taken to load and compile the bytecode.* **and** even more directly *The application code is initially interpreted, but the JVM monitors which sequences of bytecode are frequently executed and translates them to machine code for direct execution on the hardware.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, I got the point that compilation of byte code would happen on first invocation. Please post your comment as answer so that I can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple implementations of the Java Runtime Environment, so not every implementation may behave like Oracle's (and previously Sun's).

That begin said the initial invocation of a method, in *most* current implementations, involves validation and a first pass compilation of the Java bytecode. Thus, subsequent invocations of the method, are faster. However, Java also uses a JIT. Wikipedia provides an entry on [Just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) which notes

> JIT causes a slight delay to a noticeable delay in initial execution of an application, due to the time taken to load and compile the bytecode.

And, goes on to say,

> The application code is initially interpreted, but the JVM monitors which sequences of bytecode are frequently executed and translates them to machine code for direct execution on the hardware.